# incorrect output using STL remove_if

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to remove elements from a vector of ints using std::remove_if, but am not getting the required output.

Initial vector members: {0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9}

Required Output:  {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Actual Output: {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9}

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <functional>

    class Equal
    {
    public:
    Equal(int a): a_(a){}
    bool operator()(int b)
    {
    return a_ == b;
    }
    
    private:
    int a_;
    };
    
    int main()
    {
    std::vector<int> vi{0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9};
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::remove_if(vi.begin(), vi.end(), Equal(1));
    for (const auto &i : vi) std::cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just as many elements in the `vector` before and after the call to
[`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of `move` assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range.

... and `std::remove_if` returns an iterator to the start of the "removed" elements and you can use that iterator to actually `erase` the elements: See [Erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

```
vi.erase(
    std::remove_if(vi.begin(), vi.end(), Equal(1)), // returns iterator
    vi.end()                                        // erase to the end
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xs7rYYaen)

Also note that `std::vector` got a new specialized function in C++20 that does both things, namely [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2).

Example:

```
std::erase_if(vi, Equal(1));
```

Comment: Just to explain a little further: standard iterators don't support erasing elements from the container, so `std::remove_if` couldn't erase the elements if it wanted to. So we have to do that afterwards as shown in this answer. It also turns out this is a pretty efficient way of erasing elements, particularly for linear memory as with a vector.

Comment: Might help to mention that even though the number of elements are same after the call to `std::remove_if` they may not be the same elements. After the returned iterator there is essentially 'garbage'. In the question we can see 9 twice for example.

Comment: Thank you very much Ted.

Comment: @ss-haze You're welcome!